# How do I modify this code so that it replaces the last value and inserts a new value?

Tags: python, text-files

With this code I am writing to file, adding `quantity` to the same line as its corresponding `crop`.

These are the content of the text file:

```
Tomato 2 4 1
Lettuce 3 8 7
```

At the moment my code simply appends `quantity` on to the end of the line. What I want to do is insert quantity after `crop` and remove the final integer from the line.

So if I were to input 'Lettuce' for `crop` and '9' for `quantity` then the file would be modified so that it would be like this:

```
Tomato 2 4 1
Lettuce 9 3 8
```

However I'm not really sure how to do this.

My code

```
crop = input('Which crop? ')
quantity = input('How much? ')
file = ('cropdata.txt')           

if crop in open(file).read():
 with open(file, 'r') as file_read:
       lines = []

       for line in file_read:
           if crop in line:
               line = str(line.rstrip("\n") + quantity + " "  + "\n")
           lines.append(line)

 with open(file, 'w') as file_rewrite:
    file_rewrite.writelines(lines)
else:
 print('Crop not found.')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
line_parts = line.split (" ")  #possibly after stripping off final "\n"
```

Now you have an array `line_parts` consisting of `Lettuce, 3, 8,` and `7`.

You can shift the numeric entries one step to the right until you have `Lettuce, 3, 3, 8`; then replace `line_parts[0]` with your new `quantity` to get `Lettuce, 9, 8, 7`.

Let `line = line_parts[0]+line_parts[1]+line_parts[2]+line_parts[3]`, append that to lines, and continue as before.

Answer (score 0):

Don't save data like this. Use structured files to store data:

- XML
- JSON

If you will use it, this work won't difficult for you.